# Evaluating expectation of a random variable

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $v_1 ,..., v_n \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be unitary and linearly independent vectors and $X_1,...,X_n$ independent random variables ( on a specific probability space) such that every $X_i$  has a Bernoulli distribution of parameter $p_i \in [0,1]$.

a) Let $Y(w)= \sum _{i=1} ^n X_i(w) v_i$, compute the expectation of $Z$, where $Z(w)= || Y(w) -v ||^2$ with $v= \sum _{i=1}^n a_i v_i \in \mathbb{R}^n $.

b) Let V=$ \{ \sum _{i=1}^n a_i v_i|a_i \in [0,1]\}$, show that for any $v \in V$ exist an $y \in V$ such that $|| y-v||^2\le \frac{ n}{4}$ and $y= \sum _{i=1}^n b_iv_i$, with $b_i \in \{0,1\}$.
Hint: using a).

I've found this exercise online and I'm having some trouble solving point b).
I've done point a) choosing $( \mathbb{R}^n, B, P)$ as probability space, where B is Borel $\sigma $-algebra and P is equal to the product measure of $X_i$ distributions.
I've found that the expectation of Z is
\begin{align}&\sum _{i=1}^n \| (1-a_i)v_i + \sum_{j=1, j \neq i}^n (-a_j)v_j\|^2 p_i \prod_{j=1, j \neq i}^n (1-p_j)\\&+\sum _{i,j=1,i<j}^n \|(1-a_i)v_i +(1-a_j)v_j+ \sum _{k=1, k \neq i,j}^n (-a_k)v_k\|^2 p_i p_j \prod _{k=1, k \neq i,j}^n (1-p_k)+\dots\\&+\|\sum_{i=1}^n (1-a_i)v_i\|^2 \prod_{i=1}^n p_i .\end{align}

I would like to know if my solution of point a) is correct and to receive some advice for point b).

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess point b is the main issue of the exercise and it can be proved as follows.

a)) Let $y=\sum x_i v_i$, where $x_i=1$ with probability $p_i$ and $x_i=0$ with probability $1- p_i$, independently.

Then

$$\|y-v\|^2=\|\sum (x_i-a_i)v_i\|^2=\sum_{i,j=1}^n (x_i-a_i)(x_j-a_j)(v_i,v_j). $$

So $$\Bbb E\|y-v\|^2=\sum_{i,j=1\, i\ne j}^n (p_ip_j(1-a_i) (1-a_i)-p_i(1-p_j)(1-a_i)a_j-(1-p_i)p_ja_i(1-a_j)+(1-p_i)(1-p_j)a_iaj_j)(v_i,v_j)+ \sum_{i=1}^n (p_i(1-a_i)^2+(1-p_i)a_i^2)(v_i,v_i)=$$
$$\sum_{i,j=1\, i\ne j}^n (p_i-a_i)^2(v_i,v_j)+ \sum_{i=1}^n (p_i-2p_ia_i+a_i^2)(v_i,v_i)=$$
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^n (p_i-a_i)v_i, \sum_{i=1}^n (p_i-a_i)v_i\right) -\sum_{i=1}^n  (p_i-a_i)^2(v_i,v_j)+ \sum_{i=1}^n (p_i-2p_ia_i+a_i^2)(v_i,v_i)=$$
$$\left\|\sum_{i=1}^n (p_i-a_i)v_i\right\|^2+ \sum_{i=1}^n (p_i-p_i^2)(v_i,v_i).$$

b)) Choosing $p_i=a_i$ for each $i$, we obtain that
$$\Bbb E\|y-v\|^2=\sum_{i=1}^n (p_i-p_i^2)(v_i,v_i)=\sum_{i=1}^n p_i-p_i^2\le \sum_{i=1}^n \frac 14=\frac n4,$$
which implies point b.